# Will a homemade insecticide affect the taste of herbs or other edible plants?

Tags: herbs, pesticide

I'm thinking about using a homemade insecticide like a small amount of dish soap/coffee/Aloe vera mixed with water for my Stevia plant which the insects seem to like. I'm worried though that what I use in the insecticide will end up making the Stevia leaves taste of these things like soap/coffee/Aloe vera.

Will this happen? Or do you put such a small amount in the water that it would have no effect on the taste?

Comment: @insectsgoaway When editing a post, please try to fix **all** the problems with it. Thanks!

Comment: What the heck are the insects you see?  In no way would I use anything even just water to get rid of insects I have not noticed!  Much less 'MAKE UP my own concoction!!  FIND insects or problem, IDENTIFY then figure a treatment!!  Then let's talk about the treatment (S).  This is what we learn in pesticide applicator license seminars...NEVER what to use!  Always, 'what is it we should have done to prevent this from happening in the first place'!!!!  Insects are critical for plants!  To kill all insects is just wrong.  WRONG.  And to ever expect total elimination is WRONG again...sigh!

Comment: Soap is nasty tasting. When I harvest herbs, I do give them a half hour soak, with some agitation, in dilute dish soap (1 small squirt per sink full) as soap's surfactant action helps release dirt, bird poop, cobwebs, whatever may be on the leaves. But then I give the leaves at least three rinses with clean, pure water. Leaving soap residue on the leaves sounds like a bad plan.

Comment: ok, thank you wayfaring stranger! will remember this.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of organic versions you could use that will not leave a bad taste, you could just flush out the soil before harvesting and make sure all the foliage is washed carefully before eating/consuming. below is some recipes iv used in the past...

Eucalyptus Oil

A great natural pesticide for flies, bees, and wasps. Simply sprinkle a few drops of eucalyptus oil where the insects are found. They will all be gone before you know it.

Salt Spray

For treating plants infested with spider mites, mix two tablespoons of Himalayan Crystal Salt into one gallon of warm water and spray on infected areas.

Onion and Garlic Spray

Mince one organic clove of garlic and one medium sized organic onion. Add to a quart of water. Wait one hour and then add one teaspoon of cayenne pepper and one tablespoon of liquid soap to the mix. This organic spray will hold its potency for one week if stored in the refrigerator.